# Discord.js How do i spacebar in command line?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

discordjs version 11.4.2

> I type !a hello in channel but bot don't sent message

```
 if(command === "!a hello"){
  const msg = await message.channel.send("Checking Command...")
  msg.edit("hello");
 }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Pls show you "command handler", it\`s how you define you command. 
If you don\`t use discord collection for this with splitting every command to file, so you can\`t do this with right solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define 'command', but in your case you can change out `command` with `msg.content === '!a hello'`. You also don't have to define 'msg', although I suppose you could do that still.

You can do this:

```
bot.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "!a hello") {
      msg.channel.send("Checking Command...").then(msg => {
      msg.edit(`hello`);
    });
  }
});
```

Tell me if you need anything or need to remove something or add something. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have defined "command" to something like this somewhere in your code

```
const args = message.content.split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

What's causing you this problem would be this part of it: **".split(/ +/g);"**
This splits everything with a space in between into substrings. So how can you fix it now? Either use the command "!a-hello" or don't use "command"

```
if (message.content === "!a hello") {
  const msg = await message.channel.send("Checking Command...")
  msg.edit("hello");
};
```